# Does tableau have an internal database or require an external database

Tags: tableau-api

I am teaching a class on data science and I'm not familiar with tools like tableau.  One student said Tableau had an extremely efficient compression algorithm, which was kind of shocking to me.  I imagined tableau as something like metabase that was used to visualize and explore data.

So the main questions are:

1) Does tableau store data, or how does it store data?
2) Are there limits to this amount?
3) Is there any knowledge/benchmarks on its compression algorithm or querying speed?

Answer (score 1):

What they are most likely referring to is the Tableau Data Extract.

Tableau Desktop does not have a built-in database, rather it connects to different data sources (files, databases, etc). After connecting to a data source, Tableau can "extract" that data into a Tableau Data Extract file that is both compressed and represented in a columnar store format.

I'm not sure what you mean by "Are there limits to this amount?". Just remember that the Tableau Data Extract is saved as an actual file (.tde).

I imagine the algorithm/code is proprietary of Tableau and not something you would be able to review yourself.

Here is a good reference for you to learn more about TDEs:
https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2014/7/understanding-tableau-data-extracts-part1

Comment: Of course an extract **is** an efficient compressed database optimised for fast queries (and probably behaves best when in RAM). The practical limits will therefore be either disk or RAM based.

Comment: That's not exactly how it works. Tableau still queries the extract and stores the result of that query in RAM while in use - not the whole extract.

Answer (score 0):

In general, Tableau does not store data, but instead it points by reference to one or more data sources --read only --- leaving the data at rest, issuing queries, and then rendering the query results visually. It works with dozens of typical data sources.

This architecture has advantages. When the data changes, the chart can simply refresh to see the result. You can combine data from multiple sources without ETL

The one almost exception is when you create a tableau data extract as Nicarus explained. Think of extracts as persistent cached copies of a subset of the original data source. The real data is still external, there is just a local copy for speed